# Redirect most of site to HTTPS using RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, https, slim

I want my entire site to use HTTPS, except for the home page due to a non-secure script there.

The site is using Apache/Slim.

Inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" “!=/”
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,S=1]

#the usual Slim rule:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

(Note the `S=1`. That is supposed to skip the next rule if there's a match.)

Problem: I'm not being redirected and my css includes are not being served (I just get a copy of the home page html). Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you positive you cannot fix the one insecure script to make your life easier?

Comment: Yes, it's a third-party API. :\

Comment: Would you be willing to share the name of it? It might have https ability not outwardly documented. Or there might be valid alternatives (or even better ones).

Comment: I'm using CarQuery to get car years/makes/models.

Comment: Looks like that API has https ability. At least its general implementation docs mention the API url as like `https://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/...` So, you may be in luck. (PS: Thats kind of a cool API too...)

Comment: I tried switching it to HTTPS and it does in fact work. What a lot of work for such a simple solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using CarQuery, I was actually able to simply use CarQuery over HTTPS:

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.carqueryapi.com/js/carquery.0.3.4.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.carqueryapi.com/js/carquery.0.3.4.js"></script>
```

No more need to write fancy RewriteRules.

Comment: Yay now you can be fully secured and breath easier.. \o/